# CameraPreview floods parentView

Tags: android, android-camera

I have camerapreview with ratio 16:9, and i using this code for cropping it:

```
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    if (changed && getChildCount() > 0) {
        final View child = getChildAt(0);

        final int width = r - l;
        final int height = b - t;

        int previewWidth = width;
        int previewHeight = height;
        if (mPreviewSize != null) {
            previewWidth = mPreviewSize.height;
            previewHeight = mPreviewSize.width;
        }

        // Center the child SurfaceView within the parent.
        if (width * previewHeight < height * previewWidth) {
            final int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height / previewHeight;
            child.layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0,
                    (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
        } else {
            final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
            child.layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2,
                    width, (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
        }
    }
}
```

But cameraPreview floods its parentView(RelativeLayout):
Screen should be(camerapreview into green rectangle):
[image]

but in some weak devices(Android 4.1.2- API 16 below) cameraPreview become this:
[image]

As you see, cameraPreview floods its parentView but when i capture device's svreen(by holding volume down+power button), there's no problem in picture.
If someone has solution for this problem, please guide me.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Is the first screenshot OK? What is wrong on the second? That it is all black?

Comment: i solved it.
Simple, put a transparent ImageView up to CameraPreview.